# What is this error on a #define directive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, directive

I have the following line in code:

```
#define INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED 60.0
```

I get an error on this line that says, `Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2`

Did I exceed the maximum length? If so, what is the maximum length? In any case, the actual message seems absurd.

Per request, here is the context:

```
#define VITALITYSECONDS 40.0
#define MINIMUMSCALEFACTOR 0.10
#define MINIMUMSPEED 2.0
#define INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED 60.0

#pragma mark - Angle and Distance Functions

-(float)normalizeAngle:(float)angle
{
   float answer;
   // Take an angle and return a value from -pi to pi
   // To do this, we first add pi, then divide by 2pi, then take fractional part, then multiply by 2pi then subtract pi.
   answer = angle + M_PI;
   answer = answer/(2*M_PI);
   answer = answer - floor(answer);
   answer = answer * 2 * M_PI;
   answer = answer - M_PI;
   return answer;
}
```

For completeness, here is the offending line:

```
[self helpText:@"Bait arrow dispatched due to %f seconds inactivity\n",INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED];
```

And here is the corrected version:

```
[self helpText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bait arrow dispatched due to %f seconds inactivity\n",INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED]];
```

Here is the declaration for that method:

```
-(void)helpText:(NSString *)text
```

Method helpText is just a temporary method to display stuff on screen to help out the testers.

Comment: I think you must have either misread the error message or somehow got the wrong error message, because there are no method calls or arguments on that line. Are you absolutely certain this is the right file and line number?

Comment: show where you are using the defined value

Comment: Nope. That is exactly how it appears. Like I said, it's an absurd error message.

Comment: I just put this exact define in a project and it compiled with no errors, the error is either from something else entirely, or related to how you are using the defined value

Comment: If I comment out the line, the error disappears. This is just a floating point number. It's about the easiest #define there could be.

Comment: the error is not in the updated code either, i just ran it with no error

Comment: Yet another good reason not to use defines for constant values - use proper static const scalars for proper type safety.

Comment: I can't reproduce either — I just compiled the new code given and it worked fine.

Comment: The problem was actually 600 lines away, where the item was used. Now why would the error be marked at the #define instead of the line where it is used?

Comment: @VictorEngel because a #define just places that code in place _before_ it is compiled

Comment: @Till, I'm using #defines until I get a config screen put together. There will be a whole bunch of values set in a configuration screen, but it hasn't been built yet.

Comment: @wattson12, please reword what you said. I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: comments are a bit too short but i was trying to say the compiler will use the defined value (e.g. 60.0) but it will treat the location of that part of code as the place where the #define is, so if it sees an error it will point to the #define, rather than where it was incorrectly used

Comment: @Wattson12, write that as an answer, and I will check it. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I had thought that was the case but I just checked with some poorly formatted defines (and incorrectly used valid defines) and in both cases the error was reported in the place where i used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not an issue with the define. it an issue with the method.

Does the method take in an arg list ? or just a string.

Because it looks like you are trying to set a string by using a format.

try this out

```
[self helpText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bait arrow dispatched due to %f seconds inactivity\n",INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED]];
```

Comment: Yes, but why is Xcode marking the #define line with the error? Had the error been marked on the line with the problem in the first place, I would have found it right away. I didn't even consider that line to be a problem because I thought I'd just replaced a number with the #define name, but obviously I was mistaken.

Comment: the compiler works top to bottom and left to right. The issue was with the second parameter in your `[self helpText:]` message, and that parameter was a define value which caused the compiler to move over the define value then back to the point in code after it. Since the offending column and line was the define value, the only place it knew it as was where the define statement is.

Comment: @VolureDarkAngel what would the compiler have warned about if that define was supplied from outside (e.g. compiler flag -d)?

Comment: that is a good question. I dont have an answer for that one. I usually only use define statements for Macro functions that call into NSObject static methods. Rarely will i use them for values to be sprinkled about in my code. You could easily recreate the issue by putting a small project with the error and adding the compiler flag to find out... If you do, I may be interested in knowing the results.

Comment: oh. and to test they have been set or not with #ifdef

Comment: So in other words, if the point in the code identified as an error by the compiler is a #define, the compiler will point to the #define as the problem because at that point it's trying to evaluate the #define. Correct?

Comment: I believe so. But i can only speak of my own experience. Consider it a slightly biased conjecture based solely on my personal experience. with a slight bit of understanding thrown in.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint 1*:

Above the line in question, add

```
#undef INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED
```

This is just in case you define that macro differently somewhere else and now are getting weird results because of the double define. Though I must admit the error messages should be different in that case - still worth a shot, I think.

*Hint 2*:

Don't use precompiler macros (defines) for constants if not needed. There are few cases where a define makes sense and the given do not appear one of them.

Replace all of those defines with proper static const scalars;

e.g.

`static const double kInactivityTimeBeforeBaitArrowDispatched 60.0;`

That will result into type safety, well readable code and fewer head scratches.

Comment: Fair enough, but it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @VictorEngel well, I tried to address it directly with Hint1 - obviously that wasnt applying. with Hint2 I was trying to address it in a general way - sorry to be unable to convince you on that question of coding style.

Comment: the error is not related to the define statement anyhow. the error related to too many arguments. because the helpText: message did not expect extra arguments.

Comment: @Till, on the contrary, I will follow your advice. It just didn't answer my question. I expected that error message to occur on the line where helpText was called. Instead, it appeared on the #define line, so I was pursuing a red herring.

Comment: @VictorEngel I finally see your point. It is a good question. Especially if one considers that such define could have been supplied from outside your sources (e.g. compiler parameter -d).

Comment: good advice, but no answer

Comment: Of course it's an answer. It says "the problem isn't where you think it is."

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're passing *2* arguments to `-helpText:` and I'm betting it isn't variadic, so it only takes one argument.

Looks like you're trying to pass a string format and the values to place in the format specifiers. To make a string out of that, you must pass your arguments to a method that actually takes such arguments, namely `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Bait arrow dispatched due to %f seconds inactivity\n", INACTIVITYTIMEBEFOREBAITARROWDISPATCHED];
[self helpText: text];
```